# Macro to repeat the same code with 1 value changed each time, picked from a list?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm kinda new to macros in Rust... Sorry if this is already asked, but I can't find anything like this online and I'm not sure what this type of macro is even called.

Looking for something that can reduce

```rs
println!("A");
println!("B");
println!("C");
println!("D");
println!("E");
```

into

```rs
some_macro!(|value| {
  println!(value);
}, ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]);
```

Is it even possible to have Rust code inside a macro? Does it have to be a closure, or...?

Comment: Do you really want a macro here? Isn't some simple loop enough for the task? Examples: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/for.html

Comment: I know the values at compile-time, so I feel like a loop would be kinda overkill. Does the performance impact matter at all?

Comment: If it's worth unrolling it's likely the compiler will do it. I wouldn't bother thinking about performance until it's known to be a problem. The thing that is overkill here is a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
macro_rules! some_macro {
    ($logic:expr, $($arg:expr),+) => {
        {
            let logic = {$logic};
            $(logic($arg);)+
        }
    };
}

some_macro!(
    |x| println!("{x}"),
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"

);
```

Comment: You don't need the braces - `let logic = $logic;` will do.